# Reversing Motor with 2 push button switches

Tags: motor

i wanted to make a schematic to reverse the motor direction with 2 push buttons, and i failed every time to make a schematic like this, when someone can help me would it be helpful thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about momentary-contact pushbuttons or maintained-contact switches? Will you use a third pushbutton or switch to turn the motor on and off? Usual methods are a three-position switch (Fwd-Off-Rev) or three momentary buttons (Fwd, Rev, Stop).

Comment: I use momentary-contact pushbuttons

Comment: For momentary-contact pushbuttons, you need two relays each with multiple contacts. A normally-closed contact on each prevents the the other from being energized. Mechanical interlocks would be used if the voltage or power are above hobby levels. It important to know what type of motor is involved, DC, AC, single-phase, three-phase.

Comment: Once you have all of the facts, you should be able to find a diagram in a previous question here or on the internet.

Comment: its a dc motor from a windscreen wiper

Comment: dual speed or single speed? permanent magnet?.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

for permannent magnet brushed motors you need to use buttons with two contact sets,  normally open and normally closed.

eg:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fysFgO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank for this schematic but i forgot to say i use momentary-contact pushbuttons,

Comment: You need momentary action pushbuttons with changeover contacts. If you have other constraints you need to put these in the question and not in the comments.

Comment: @Transistor What are "changeover contacts"? I've been an engineer for a long time and never heard that term.

Comment: A changeover contact is a combined normally open (NO) and normally closed (NC) with a common wiper as indicated by SW1 and SW2 in Jasen's schematic. Single-pole, double-throw (SPDT) is an alternative description and may be more common in some parts of the world but then what's a pole and what's a throw?

Answer (score 1):

The following diagram shows the circuit that I would use.

[image]